# linaro-hwpack-create facing problems

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, odroid

I have to create a hwpack using linaro for odroidxu4.

Currently I am following this [link](http://linuxfactory.or.kr/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=how_to_create_ubuntu_image_with_linaro_image_tools) to create a hwpack.

I have uboot, linux, uboot and firstboot .deb files in a /temp. And also the config for odroidxu4 and linaro-hwpack-create in the same /temp.

so while executing, i am facing this issue

```
/temp$ linaro-hwpack-create odroidxu4 1
Building for armhf
Fetching packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bin/linaro-image-tools-master/linaro-hwpack-create", line 57, in <module>
    builder.build()
  File "/home/bin/linaro-image-tools-master/linaro_image_tools/hwpack/builder.py", line 228, in build
    with fetcher:
  File "/homebin/linaro-image-tools-master/linaro_image_tools/hwpack/packages.py", line 639, in prepare
    self.cache.prepare()
  File "/home/bin/linaro-image-tools-master/linaro_image_tools/hwpack/packages.py", line 570, in prepare
    raise FetchFailedException(obfuscated_e)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to export your proxy user name and password

> export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/

Actually this error happens due to fetching the file from the repository